# How to pass argument that is not input field in laravel blade?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I can pass input field value to controller by using format that shown below

```
       <form method="GET" action="{{Request::fullUrl()}}">
```

However, how can I pass the value that is not input field such as bootstrap dropdown value ?

And anyone know how to set request argument using laravel 5 ?
for example, Request::get('search') gives me baseurl/search=

This is example of non input field

```
 <div id="filterDropDown" class="btn-group col-md-3">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info dropDownTitle">Filter</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"
        aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="caret"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
</button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" style="left:14px">
    <li value=""><a  href="#">All Records</a></li>
    <li value="Waiting"><a  href="#">Waiting</a></li>
    <li value="Resolved"><a  href="#">Resolved</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you more elaborate? Creating a search form is different think. I don't understand this, `how can I pass the value that is not input field such as bootstrap dropdown value?`

Comment: all the input field value will pass via url in get request when I click button right ? But how to pass non input field values ? .. is it more clear?

Comment: What do you mean by `non input field`? Give a plain html example.

Comment: such as bootstrap dropdown which does not have input  tag.

Comment: You mean `<select></select>`?

Comment: I edit my question in order to give you example of non input field

Comment: You want to pass the value of selected `<li>`?

Comment: Yes thats what I want to do

Comment: You have to pass the value using anchor tag. Ex: `<a href="{{ action('YourController@method',[$theValueYouWantToPass]) }}"></a>`

Comment: First of all, it calls index function in controller so I do not want to pass anything. I want to pass  values via url. Url should be look like users?search=name:John Doe;email:john@gmail.com

Comment: Are you creating a search form, where there is multiple dropdown?

Comment: I am creating simple a search form which contains a dropdown and a text input field.

Comment: You can easily do this using `<select>`. Bootstrap Dropdown is usually used for menu or sidebar. It would be better if you share search form's code.

Comment: Thanks for helping me but I cannot do that .. it has to be this and use certain url format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to achieve what you're asking is to add the value of the dropdown to a hidden input field. Start by adding in the field:

```
<input type="hidden" name="dropdown" />
```

Then, add some jQuery that will update the value of the hidden input field when the dropdown menu is clicked:

```
$('.dropdown-menu a').click(function() {
    $('[name="dropdown"]').val( $(this).text() );
});
```

Then a link in the dropdown is clicked, it will populate the hidden field with the text. Take a look at this [jsfiddle for a working example](https://jsfiddle.net/yedtc279/).

Comment: Oh I did little longer way    <input type="text" name="status"  value="{{Request::get('stat')}}"  style="visibility:hidden;display:none"/>